# Python: how do I resolve AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face_recognition_model_v1'

Tags: python, face-detection, face-recognition, dlib

I have downloaded the file and placed it in the same directory from where I am running my code. But here `facerec = dlib.face_recognition_model_v1(face_rec_model_path)` I am still getting this Atribute error. i have given the full to where it is but still error.
this is my code, I am not able to identify where the problem is ?

```
import sys
import os
import dlib
import glob
from skimage import io

predictor_path = '/home/irum/Desktop/DLIB-recognition/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat'
face_rec_model_path = '/home/irum/Desktop/DLIB-recognition/dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat'
faces_folder_path = '/home/irum/Desktop/DLIB-recognition/att_faces/ERSHIAN'

# Load all the models we need: a detector to find the faces, a shape predictor
# to find face landmarks so we can precisely localize the face, and finally the

# face recognition model.
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
sp = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path)
facerec = dlib.face_recognition_model_v1(face_rec_model_path)

win = dlib.image_window()

# Now process all the images
for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(faces_folder_path, "*.png")):
    print("Processing file: {}".format(f))
    img = io.imread(f)

    win.clear_overlay()
    win.set_image(img)

    # Ask the detector to find the bounding boxes of each face. The 1 in the
    # second argument indicates that we should upsample the image 1 time. This
    # will make everything bigger and allow us to detect more faces.
    dets = detector(img, 1)
    print("Number of faces detected: {}".format(len(dets)))

    # Now process each face we found.
    for k, d in enumerate(dets):
        print("Detection {}: Left: {} Top: {} Right: {} Bottom: {}".format(
            k, d.left(), d.top(), d.right(), d.bottom()))
        # Get the landmarks/parts for the face in box d.
        shape = sp(img, d)
        # Draw the face landmarks on the screen so we can see what face is currently being processed.
        win.clear_overlay()
        win.add_overlay(d)
        win.add_overlay(shape)


        face_descriptor = facerec.compute_face_descriptor(img, shape)
        print(face_descriptor)

        dlib.hit_enter_to_continue()
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that `dlib` doesn't have an attribute called `face_recognition_model_v1`.  I don't know what dlib is so I can't tell you any more than that, but you could check the dlib.py file you downloaded and check there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update dlib. Run this command: `pip install dlib==19.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install dlib.
Run
`pip install dlib`

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: dlib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dlib-19.2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg

Comment: have you tried the latest dlib? run pip install dlib==19.4.0.